# ps2pdf with OCR loose OCR

Tags: ghostscript

I have sought lots of my times to convert ps2pdf with OCR.

I installed GhostScript on my Windows10 and converted a pdf with OCR into Post Script file. Then I converted PDF from Post Script to get better result.

What happened was lost OCR.

How to convert OCRed pdf to Post Script file then back to Post Script file to PDF with OCR?

My command was

```
pdf2ps test.pdf test.ps
```

Then

```
gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o test2.pdf test.ps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve the goal you are attempting using Ghostscript or, most likely, any other PostScript interpreter.

The PostScript language does not support some features of the PDF model, in this case it does not support Text Rendering Modes. The PDF file almost certainly uses Text Rendering Mode 3 to place 'invisible' text on the page. (NB this is somewhat a guess, since you have not supplied a PDF file to investigate)

The PostScript emitted by the ps2write device mimics this by not drawing the text.

When you take that PostScript and create a PDF file from it, the text is not drawn, so it is not incorporated into the PDF file. The result is that the Tr 3 and the text is not present in the new PDF file.

Since you had a PDF file in the first place, simply don't create a PostScript program from it, and you will have what you want, a PDF file with invisible text in it.